# Simplifying a routine to run faster

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, event-handling

I have this below change event macro
The purpose of the macro is to prepare a quote master for the items entered.
The data to be entered in the cells starting B15( which is for the item number) and E15(which is for the quantity)
The workbook is having 3 additional sheets
Stocklist5104(A: Item number, B: Description, C:Quantity)
Stocklist5102(A: Item number, B: Description, C:Quantity)
PriceList(A: PN, B: Supersede, C: Part Name, D: Stock, E: COST, F: Sale Price, G: Remarks, H: TAG, I: , J: P0, K: P1, L: P2, M: P3, N: P4)

Once the data is entered in B15, all other cells till T will be populated with these formulas.
I have placed two sections, in which the user can enter data manually one by one or else can copy paste a set of values to the column B starting B15.

- Column A - for serial numbers
- Column D - will pull the description from the sheet PriceList which
  is in the same workbook
- Column F - will check if the value in cell AA1 is 1 or two as I have
  given an option box to select 5104 or 5102, it will pull the value
  from column C of stocklist5104 or 5102 respectively.
- Column H,J,K,L,N,O,Q,R - will do the calculations as per the formulas
  Column M & P- can enter values so that the near by cell can calculate
  accordingly, its optional
- Column S & T - will pull data from sheet Pricelist worksheet.

Everything works fine, but I want to check if I have made this macro complicated to make it run slow.
The data entering in B column can be either 1 or 1000 at same time.

adding the full code for better undertstanding.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B:B")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Application.CutCopyMode And IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric(Target) Then        ' Check if cell contains a numeric value or is not empty and the change was made by the user
        If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then        ' Check if multiple cells are selected
        Dim deleteRows As Range        ' Create a range object to store rows to delete
        Dim lastrow As Long
        
        For Each cell In Target.Cells
            If cell.Value <> "" Then
                
                UnProtectSheet
                
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
                
                Range("A" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",ROW()-ROW($A$15)+1,""""),0)"
                Range("H" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",G" & cell.row & "*F" & cell.row & ",""""),0)"
                Range("D" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$C$4:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),"""")"
                Range("G" & cell.row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!R4C9:R10000C14,IFERROR(MATCH(RC[-5],PriceList!R4C1:R10000C1,0),MATCH(RC[-4],PriceList!R4C1:R10000C1,0)),MATCH(Customer_Database!R3C3,{""P1"",""P2"",""P3"",""P4"",""P5"",""P0""},0)),"""")"
                Range("F" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$1=2,IF(E" & cell.row & ">INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),E" & cell.row & "),IF(E" & cell.row & ">INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),E" & cell.row & ")),0)"
                Range("I" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$1=2,INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0))),0)"
                Range("K" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$E$4:$E$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),0)"
                Range("J" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",K" & cell.row & "*F" & cell.row & ",""""),0)"
                Range("L" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",G" & cell.row & "/K" & cell.row & "-1,""""),IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",(G" & cell.row & "/K" & cell.row & "-1)-5%,"""")),0)"
                Range("N" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",M" & cell.row & "/K" & cell.row & "-1,""""),IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",(M" & cell.row & "/K" & cell.row & "-1)-5%,"""")),0)"
                Range("O" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",M" & cell.row & "*F" & cell.row & ",""""),0)"
                Range("Q" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",P" & cell.row & "/K" & cell.row & "-1,""""),IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",(P" & cell.row & "/K" & cell.row & "-1)-5%,"""")),0)"
                Range("R" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & cell.row & "<>"""",P" & cell.row & "*F" & cell.row & ",""""),0)"
                Range("S" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$G$4:$G$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),"""")"
                Range("T" & cell.row).Value = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$H$4:$H$7956,MATCH(B" & cell.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),"""")"
                
                Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
                
                ' Set horizontal alignment and formatting for the cells
                With Range("A" & cell.row)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                End With
                With Range("B" & cell.row & ":D" & cell.row)
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
                End With
                
                Dim rng1 As Range
                Set rng1 = Union(Range("E" & cell.row), Range("F" & cell.row), Range("I" & cell.row), Range("H8:H10"))
                
                With rng1
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                    .NumberFormat = "0"
                End With
                
                With Range("M" & cell.row)
                    .Interior.Color = RGB(146, 2089, 80)
                End With
                
                Dim rng2 As Range
                Set rng2 = Union(Range("G" & cell.row), Range("H" & cell.row), Range("J" & cell.row), _
                    Range("K" & cell.row), Range("M" & cell.row), Range("O" & cell.row), Range("P" & cell.row), Range("R" & cell.row), _
                    Range("H11"), Range("M6"), Range("M8"), Range("M10"))
                
                With rng2
                    .NumberFormat = "0.00_-;[Red]-0.00_-;""-""??_-;@"
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                End With
                
                Dim rng3 As Range
                Set rng3 = Union(Range("N" & cell.row), Range("L" & cell.row), Range("Q" & cell.row), Range("M7"), _
                    Range("M9"), Range("M11"))
                
                With rng3
                    .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                    .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
                End With
                
                ' Copy border, border color and orientation from row above
                With Range("A" & cell.row & ":T" & cell.row)
                    .Borders.LineStyle = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.LineStyle
                    .Borders.Color = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.Color
                    .Orientation = .Offset(-1, 0).Orientation
                    .HorizontalAlignment = .Offset(-1, 0).HorizontalAlignment
                End With
                ProtectSheet
                
            Else
                ' Add row to deleteRows range
                If deleteRows Is Nothing Then
                    Set deleteRows = Rows.Item(cell.row)
                Else
                    Set deleteRows = Union(deleteRows, Rows.Item(cell.row))
                End If
            End If
        Next cell
        
        UnProtectSheet
        
        'Formatting of the Header cells
        With Range("H8:H10")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .NumberFormat = "0"
        End With
        
        With Range("H11")
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .NumberFormat = "0.00_-;[Red]-0.00_-;""-""??_-;@"
        End With
        
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        'Calculations for the header cells
        lastrow = Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
        Range("H6").Value = "=TODAY()"
        Range("H9").Value = "=IFERROR(SUM(E15:E" & lastrow & "),"""")"
        Range("H8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B15:B" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row))
        Range("H10").Value = "=IFERROR(SUM(F15:F" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row & "),"""")"
        Range("H11").Value = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(H15:H" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M6").Value = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(J15:J" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M7").Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,ROUND(H11/M6-1,2),ROUND((H11/M6-1)-5%,2)),"""")"
        Range("M8").Value = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(O15:O" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M9").Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,ROUND(M8/M6-1,2),ROUND((M8/M6-1)-5%,2)),"""")"
        Range("M10").Value = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(R15:R" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
        Range("M11").Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,ROUND(M10/M6-1,2),ROUND((M10/M6-1)-5%,2)),"""")"
        
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        
        ProtectSheet
        
        ' Delete entire rows in deleteRows range
        If Not deleteRows Is Nothing Then
            
            UnProtectSheet
            
            Application.EnableEvents = False        ' Disable events to avoid triggering the event again
            deleteRows.Delete
            Application.EnableEvents = True        ' Enable events again
            
            ProtectSheet
            
        End If
        
    Else
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            
            UnProtectSheet
            
            Debug.Print Target
            Debug.Print Target.row
            
            Range("A" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",ROW()-ROW($A$15)+1,""""),0)"
            Range("D" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$C$4:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),"""")"
            Range("F" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$1=2,IF(E" & Target.row & ">INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),E" & Target.row & "),IF(E" & Target.row & ">INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),E" & Target.row & ")),0)"
            Range("G" & Target.row).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!R4C9:R10000C14,IFERROR(MATCH(RC[-5],PriceList!R4C1:R10000C1,0),MATCH(RC[-4],PriceList!R4C1:R10000C1,0)),MATCH(Customer_Database!R3C3,{""P1"",""P2"",""P3"",""P4"",""P5"",""P0""},0)),"""")"
            Range("H" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",G" & Target.row & "*F" & Target.row & ",""""),0)"
            Range("I" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$1=2,INDEX(StockList5104!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5104!$A$2:$A$7956,0)),INDEX(StockList5102!$C$2:$C$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",StockList5102!$A$2:$A$7956,0))),0)"
            Range("J" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",K" & Target.row & "*F" & Target.row & ",""""),0)"
            Range("K" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$E$4:$E$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),0)"
            Range("L" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",G" & Target.row & "/K" & Target.row & "-1,""""),IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",(G" & Target.row & "/K" & Target.row & "-1)-5%,"""")),0)"
            Range("N" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",M" & Target.row & "/K" & Target.row & "-1,""""),IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",(M" & Target.row & "/K" & Target.row & "-1)-5%,"""")),0)"
            Range("O" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",M" & Target.row & "*F" & Target.row & ",""""),0)"
            Range("Q" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",P" & Target.row & "/K" & Target.row & "-1,""""),IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",(P" & Target.row & "/K" & Target.row & "-1)-5%,"""")),0)"
            Range("R" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(IF(B" & Target.row & "<>"""",P" & Target.row & "*F" & Target.row & ",""""),0)"
            Range("S" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$G$4:$G$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),"""")"
            Range("T" & Target.row).Value = "=IFERROR(INDEX(PriceList!$H$4:$H$7956,MATCH(B" & Target.row & ",PriceList!$A$4:$A$7956,0)),"""")"
            
            ' Set horizontal alignment
            With Range("A" & Target.row)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            End With
            With Range("B" & Target.row & ":D" & Target.row)
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
            End With
            
            With Range("M" & Target.row)
                .Interior.Color = RGB(146, 2089, 80)
            End With
            
            Dim rnge1 As Range
            Set rnge1 = Union(Range("E" & Target.row), Range("F" & Target.row), Range("I" & Target.row), Range("H8:H10"))
            
            With rnge1
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .NumberFormat = "0"
            End With
            
            Dim rnge2 As Range
            Set rnge2 = Union(Range("G" & Target.row), Range("H" & Target.row), Range("J" & Target.row), _
                Range("K" & Target.row), Range("M" & Target.row), Range("O" & Target.row), Range("P" & Target.row), Range("R" & Target.row), _
                Range("H11"), Range("M6"), Range("M8"), Range("M10"))
            
            With rnge2
                .NumberFormat = "0.00_-;[Red]-0.00_-;""-""??_-;@"
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            End With
            
            Dim rnge3 As Range
            Set rnge3 = Union(Range("N" & Target.row), Range("L" & Target.row), Range("Q" & Target.row), Range("M7"), Range("M9"), Range("M11"))
            
            With rnge3
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
                .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
            End With
            
            ' Copy border, border color and orientation from row above
            With Range("A" & Target.row & ":T" & Target.row)
                .Borders.LineStyle = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.LineStyle
                .Borders.Color = .Offset(-1, 0).Borders.Color
                .Orientation = .Offset(-1, 0).Orientation
                .HorizontalAlignment = .Offset(-1, 0).HorizontalAlignment
            End With
            
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            
            lastrow = Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row
            
            Range("H6").Value = "=TODAY()"
            Range("H8").Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B15:B" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).row))
            Range("H9").Value = "=IFERROR(SUM(E15:E" & lastrow & "),"""")"
            Range("H10").Value = "=IFERROR(SUM(F15:F" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).row & "),"""")"
            Range("H11").Value = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(H15:H" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
            Range("M6").Value = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(J15:J" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
            Range("M7").Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,ROUND(H11/M6-1,2),ROUND((H11/M6-1)-5%,2)),"""")"
            Range("M8").Value = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(O15:O" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
            Range("M9").Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,ROUND(M8/M6-1,2),ROUND((M8/M6-1)-5%,2)),"""")"
            Range("M10").Value = "=IFERROR(ROUND(SUM(R15:R" & Cells.Item(Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).row & "),2),"""")"
            Range("M11").Value = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2,ROUND(M10/M6-1,2),ROUND((M10/M6-1)-5%,2)),"""")"
            
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            
            ProtectSheet
            
        Else
            
            ' Delete entire row
            
            UnProtectSheet
            
            Application.EnableEvents = False        ' Disable events to avoid triggering the event again
            Rows.Item(Target.row).Delete
            Application.EnableEvents = True        ' Enable events again
            
            ProtectSheet
            
        End If
        
    End If
    
End If

End If

' Protect the worksheet again if it was previously protected

End Sub

Private Function IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric(selection As Range) As Boolean
    IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric = False
    For Each cell In selection.Cells
        If IsNumeric(cell.Value) Or cell.Value <> "" Then
            IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell
End Function
```

Comment: If you try using VBA, then use VBA. I mean, renounce to formulas, place the range to be processed in an array to make all operations in memory and place the calculated result in an array, too, Then, drop the processed array content at once, at the end of the code. Anyhow, you only show a not eloquent slice of your code. At least, make calculations manual and Screen Updating `False` at the beginning and `Automatic`/`False` at the end... Writing once at a time and using formulas consumes a lot of Excel resources and make the code slow.

Comment: right now i have placed `Range("A" & cell.row).Value`, is this faster or `Range("A" & cell.row).Formula` is faster

Comment: There is a Code Review Stack for this.

Comment: Your question is bad from more points of view, I 'm afraid... 1. You should sate that the code is a slice of a change event. 2. All part related to **cells formatted must be taken out from the code**!. You should format that columns once and filling values without copying will not bother he format. This is showing down the code. 3. You should create an array, something like: `arr = Me.Range("A" & Target.Row, "T" & Target.Row + Target.cells.count).value2'. Then fill each array element with each calculated value and drop it after processing.

Comment: Dropping its content in 'Me.Range("A" & Target.Row).resize(Ubound(arr), Ubound(arr, 2)).value2`.

Comment: @FaneDuru I am so sorry, i am new to this and not aware of fully explaining the scenarios.

Comment: No problem, this is something being learned in time... I only tried explaining what's wrong and suggested what (I think) it would be good. If you edit your question and **clearly explain what you need to take from other pages and based on what**, to avoid reading your formulas, I will try posting a piece of code to start with...

Comment: @FaneDuru I checked for the option of uploading the xlsm file itself, but couldnt find a way, I will edit my posts with more details. if there is an option over here to upload the file, let me know

Comment: You can place the file on a transfer site ([Here](https://easyupload.io/)], for instance is one free and easy to be used). Not very recommended here, because if its limited period of staying online, but you did it at request... :) You may delete your comment after some time, to avoid confusing others who may be interested, even it is not so probable, I think... Sending the file is useful to also check the code. Otherwise, it will not be tested, not having the necessary environment and not loosing too much time to build it from scratch...

Comment: OK. I will download the workbook and look at it. If I have something not clear, I will ask. No too much availability, I will try understanding what ( exactly is to be done and adapt the part treating a row. I will maybe create a function to be called by iteration of the other multiple rows changed.

Comment: I can see in the used formulas more dependencies to the sheet cells, besides changed cells in B:B... I mean the value in F:F column depends by the one in E:E, the value in N:N depends by ones from M:M and K:K and so on... Everything is also dependent of "AA1" or "AA2" I thought that you only need to rapidly bring values from other sheets, ranges and place here. If you add values in the dependent cells **after the event running**, you cannot keep them dynamically updated... Only some formulas looks to not have dependencies.

Comment: I am trying to make a mixture between formulas and values but I cannot verify the formula bringing the value in G:G. In sheet "Customer_Database" the cell "B3" used as reference has an error (`=#REF!C7`) and it is also dependent on column F:F...

Comment: What you said is correct, as there are so many dependencies in most of the cells, and the value in G:G is related to customer database cell B3, as the customer code changes the value in G:G also changes. just make the company name in customer database column A to demo company1, 2 3 and so on, so it will be fine.

Comment: I understood that "value in G:G is related to customer database cell B3" looking to the formula. The problem is that in B3 is '=#REF!C7'... Where from this data is taken? I deduced that it should one of the P0, P1, P.... columns header where from to extract the price. Is this correct? Did you delete any sheet when prepared the dummy file and because of that it lost the sheet name reference? I have in mind something able to increase the speed and make the code more compact but I need to know what to be in that B3. At least, to confirm that something like `Px`...

Comment: And, in order to be sure that I will see your comment, you must tag me (@FaneDuru)... Otherwise, I am not notified about your comment. Now, it only happens that I came here and checked...

Comment: @FaneDuru: no sheets have been deleted, only you need to change the demo customer names to demo customer1, 2 3 and so on, which was changed. and the cell B3 is taken from Quote_Master!C7.

Comment: **from `Quote_Master!C7`**? In such a case, it shows `Customer ID` and the code looks to make sense only if it will be `Pricing Modifier`. The (`Vlookup`) formula from "Quote_Master" should be adapted to return from the fifth column... Am I missing anything? Only in this way the formula in column G:G from "Quote_Master" looks to make sense... I have in mind to build simplified formulas with only the exactly cell address (determined in VBA), but to do it I need to be sure that my understanding about what you try doing is correct...

Comment: In such circumstances, according to my understanding, the formula should be `=VLOOKUP(C6,Customer_Database!$A$5:$E$700,5,0)`... To return "P4" for the demo company... Shouldn't it be a correct understanding of the situation?

Comment: sorry if am making you confused, cell B3 is linked to Quote_Master!C7 and once its changed C3 changes accordingly to P1, P2, P3, P4 or P5 by indexing, and G:G value is dependent on C3, like if the customer is P3 the corresponding value from Pricelist worksheet is returned. i hope i didnt confused you more

Comment: You forgot tagging me... What I was trying to suggest is the fact that the `Vlookup` formula from the dummy workbook you sent was wrong. It used to return `Customer ID`, instead of `Pricing Modifier`. Please, look to the file you sent! Otherwise, it would be difficult to understand what I'm saying. So, in B3 should be a pricing modifier, as I assumed. If so, I think I have a global understanding to make a scenario and work on it. If not, please what is to be changed in my understanding. But **do not forget to tag me**! You are notified about my comments only because you placed the question...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252869/discussion-between-san-jay-and-faneduru).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted solution. It uses an array of formulas to be filled and its result is dropped at once, at the end of the code. It calculates an equivalent of your original (complicated) formulas, which needed a lot of Excel resources. I skipped the part which protect/unprotect the sheet and working on suppositions, it probably could be improved. But is should be faster. I also skipped the part which used to format the processed/added range. It can be easily done at once for a reasonable number of rows:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim lastR As Long: lastR = Me.Range("B" & Me.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
  Dim rngBB As Range: Set rngBB = Me.Range("B15:B" & lastR)
  
  If Not Intersect(Target, rngBB) Is Nothing Then
        If Not Application.CutCopyMode And IsSelectionNotEmptyOrNumeric(Target) Then ' Check if cell contains a numeric value or is not empty and the change was made by the user
            Dim arr, i As Long, rngDel As Range
            
            If Target.Rows.Count > 1 Then
                    arr = Me.Range("A" & Target.row, "T" & Target.row + Target.Rows.Count - 1).Formula
                    arr = fillArray(arr, Intersect(Target, rngBB), rngDel)
                    
                    Application.EnableEvents = False
                     Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Formula = arr 'drop the processed array content, at once
                     
                      'delete the empty rows, if the case:
                     If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
                    Application.EnableEvents = True
            Else
                   Application.EnableEvents = False
                    If Intersect(Target, rngBB).Value = "" Then  'delete the row if Target is empty
                           Target.EntireRow.Delete
                         Application.EnableEvents = True
                           Exit Sub
                    End If
                    
                   arr = Me.Range("A" & Target.row, "T" & Target.row).Formula
                   
                   arr = fillArray(arr, Intersect(Target, rngBB), rngDel)
                   Target.Offset(0, -1).Resize(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2)).Formula = arr
                   Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End If
  End If
End Sub

Function fillArray(arr As Variant, Targ As Range, ByRef rngDel As Range) As Variant
    Dim findC As Range, wsPrL As Worksheet, wsCustD As Worksheet, wsSt5104 As Worksheet, wsSt5102 As Worksheet
    Dim mtch, strFormulaF As String, strFormulaI As String, i As Long
    
    Set wsPrL = Me.Parent.Worksheets("PriceList")
    Set wsCustD = Me.Parent.Worksheets("Customer_Database")
    Set wsSt5104 = Me.Parent.Worksheets("StockList5104")
    Set wsSt5102 = Me.Parent.Worksheets("StockList5102")

   For i = 1 To UBound(arr)
               'check if the target row is empty in its second column (to delete the row):_
               If arr(i, 2) = "" Then
                    addToRange rngDel, Range("A" & Targ.row + i - 1)
                    GoTo SkipFilling
               End If
               '________________________________________________________________________
               
               'solve D:D, K:K, G:G, S:S data from PriceList sheet_________________________________________________________________________
               Set findC = wsPrL.Range("A:A").Find(what:=CStr(arr(i, 2)), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'Find in "PriceList"
               If Not findC Is Nothing Then
                    arr(i, 4) = "=" & findC.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0, , True)    'place Description in D:D
                    arr(i, 11) = "=" & findC.Offset(, 4).Address(0, 0, , True)  'place Cost in K:K
                    arr(i, 19) = "=" & findC.Offset(, 6).Address(0, 0, , True)  'place Remarks in S:S
                    arr(i, 20) = "=" & findC.Offset(, 7).Address(0, 0, , True)  'place Tag in T:T
                    
                    mtch = Application.Match(wsCustD.Range("B3").Value, wsPrL.Range("I3:N3").Value, 0)  ' match the appropriate "P" type
                    If Not IsError(mtch) Then arr(i, 7) = "=" & wsPrL.Cells(findC.row, mtch + 8).Address(0, 0, , True)  'place the price in G:G
                Else
                    arr(i, 4) = "Not found in ""PriceList""..."
                    arr(i, 1) = "=IF(" & Targ.Offset(i - 1).Address(0, 0) & "<>"""",ROW()-14)"
                    GoTo SkipFilling
               End If
               '__________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
               
               'Simple formulas on the same Quote_Master sheet_____________________________________________________________________
               arr(i, 1) = "=IF(" & Targ.Offset(i - 1).Address(0, 0) & "<>"""",ROW()-14)" 'current number in A:A
               
               arr(i, 8) = "=" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 4).Address(0, 0) & "*" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 5).Address(0, 0)    'in H:H (F * G)"
               
               arr(i, 10) = "=" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 4).Address(0, 0) & "*" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 9).Address(0, 0)  'in H:H (F * K)"
               
               arr(i, 12) = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2," & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 5).Address(0, 0) & "/" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 9).Address(0, 0) & _
                                     "-1,(" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 5).Address(0, 0) & "/" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 9).Address(0, 0) & "-1)-5%),0)" 'In L:L
               
               arr(i, 14) = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2," & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 11).Address(0, 0) & "/" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 9).Address(0, 0) & _
                                   "-1,(" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 11).Address(0, 0) & "/" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 9).Address(0, 0) & "-1)-5%),0)" 'in N:N
                                   
                arr(i, 15) = "=IFERROR(" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 11).Address(0, 0) & "*" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 4).Address(0, 0) & ",0)" 'in O:O

                arr(i, 17) = "=IFERROR(IF($AA$2=2," & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 14).Address(0, 0) & "/" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 9).Address(0, 0) & _
                                      "- 1,(" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 14).Address(0, 0) & "/" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 9).Address(0, 0) & "-1)-5%),0)" 'In Q:Q
                                      
                arr(i, 18) = "=IFERROR(" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 14).Address(0, 0) & "*" & Targ.Offset(i - 1, 4).Address(0, 0) & ",0)"  'in R:R
               '________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
               
               'Solve F:F and I:I________________________________________________________________________________________________________
               Set findC = wsSt5104.Range("A:A").Find(what:=CStr(arr(i, 2)), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'Find in "StockList5104"
                 If Not findC Is Nothing Then
                        strFormulaF = "=If($AA$1=2,IF(" & findC.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0, , True) & ">0," & _
                                           findC.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0, , True) & ",E" & Targ.row + i - 1 & "),IF("  'extract stock from "StockList5104"
                        strFormulaI = "=If($AA$1=2," & findC.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0, , True) & ","
                 Else
                        strFormulaF = "=If($AA$1=2,IF(0>0,0,E" & Targ.row + i - 1 & "),IF("
                        strFormulaI = "=If($AA$1=2,0,"
                 End If
                 
               Set findC = wsSt5102.Range("A:A").Find(what:=CStr(arr(i, 2)), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole) 'Find in "StockList5102"
                 If Not findC Is Nothing Then
                        strFormulaF = strFormulaF & findC.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0, , True) & ">0," & _
                                            findC.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0, , True) & ",E" & Targ.row + i - 1 & "))"    'extract stock from "StockList5102"
                        strFormulaI = strFormulaI & findC.Offset(, 2).Address(0, 0, , True) & ")"
                 Else
                        strFormulaF = strFormulaF & "0>0,0,E" & Targ.row + i - 1 & "))"
                        strFormulaI = strFormulaI & "0)"
                 End If
                arr(i, 6) = strFormulaF  ' simplified formula for stock inf F:F
                arr(i, 9) = strFormulaI   ' simplified formula for stock inf I:I
               '_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________________
               
SkipFilling:
    Next i
    
       fillArray = arr 'return the processed array
End Function

Sub addToRange(rngU As Range, rng As Range)
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
        Set rngU = rng
    Else
        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rng)
    End If
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

**Edited**:

In order to avoid formatting for each sheet change event, the next `Sub` should be run from time to time. The number of rows to be formatted is kept in the sheet "A5" cell (with white font color). For 10000 rows (just for testing) it takes about two, to three seconds:

```
Sub formatQuote_Master()
    Dim wsQM As Worksheet, rngForm As Range, lastFRow As Long, arrBord, El
    
    arrBord = Application.Evaluate("Row(7:12)") 'used to place cells borders
    
    Set wsQM = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Quote_Master")
    lastFRow = wsQM.Range("A5") 'with white font in A5 (1000 to test it)
    
    Set rngForm = wsQM.Range("A15", "T" & lastFRow)
    With rngForm
        .Columns(1).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter                                                        '"A:A"
        Union(.Columns(2), .Columns(3), .Columns(4)).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft '"B:D"
        .Columns(2).NumberFormat = "@" 'some Part Number codes start with leading zero
        With Union(.Columns(5), .Columns(6), .Columns(9))                                           '"E:F, I:I"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .NumberFormat = "0"
        End With
        .Columns(13).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 2089, 80)                                              '"M:M"
        With Union(.Columns(7), .Columns(8), .Columns(10), .Columns(11), _
                               .Columns(13), .Columns(15), .Columns(16), .Columns(18))        '"G:G, H:H, J:J, K:K, M:M, O:O, P:P, R:R"
            .NumberFormat = "0.00_-;[Red]-0.00_-;""-""??_-;@"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        End With
        With Union(.Columns(12), .Columns(14), .Columns(17)) '"L:L, N:N, Q:Q"
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
            .NumberFormat = "0.00%"
        End With
        
        For Each El In arrBord 'place borders on the range cells:
            With .Borders(El)
                .LineStyle = xlContinuous: .Weight = xlThin: .ColorIndex = 0
            End With
       Next El
    End With
    
    MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The code can be easily adapted to use two such cells and format starting from the already formatted row adding a specific constant number (took from another cell). As it is, it is faster than the way you are trying formatting in your code. It can be adapted to receive parameters and even being called from the event. If you do not like having the whole estimated range previously formatted...

The format above the 15th row should be done manually, because it needs to be done **only once**.

Comment: @San Jay Please, download from [here](https://easyupload.io/jlgaqd) the updated workbook and make some tests. Then send some feedback, please.

Comment: Thanks for the support, Let me check and try it out, will update you the feedback shortly, really appreciate your effort, i tried the speed and its so much faster than mine.